# Angular .run not cicking in?

Tags: angularjs

I trying to put some code in .run block in my angular application. What i want to do is watch my routes change and flag some links based on permission user have.

here is a structure of my application

this is my main module where I will inject my other modules

```
angular.module('app', ['app.bms', 'app.core' , 'app.reports']);
```

this is my core module where i inject all the 3rd party modules

```
  angular.module('app.core', 
["ngAnimate","ngTable","angularSpinner",'ui.router',"ui.bootstrap","ngFileUpload", "chart.js"]);
```

this is where im trying to do .run blovk in my main application

```
angular
        .module("app.bms", [])
        .run(['$rootScope', 'authService', function ($rootScope,authService) {
            console.log("running");
        }
        ]);
```

here is my html where i start app

```
  <div ng-app="app">
```

i never hit my console running.

any idea what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Did you add `ng-app="app.bms"` to any DOM element?

Comment: @mparnisari - please take a look i updated my question. This is where i start my app and just inject views in this page. i was wondering if i inject rest of my modules in app wouldn't it make them load as well?

Comment: In what module `authService` service created?

Comment: Take a look [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/e04cuv4h/)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, thank you for example. In my case service is on `app.bms`
I used app just as default module to inject everything else into it. Do you think this could be bad design?

Comment: This is normal design. It should work as expect. Maybe you have another issue. Do you have any errors in console? Try to add console.log on modules `app.core` and `app` in function `run` .